# Python IndexError only occurs on osx but not linux

Tags: python, linux, macos

I'm parsing an RGB .jpg file and it parses fine in linux, but not in mac osx. Both are version 2.7.9

Here's the code:

```
import numpy
import Image
from StringIO import StringIO
import urllib

def main():

    # process terrain input
    terrain_image = numpy.asarray(Image.open(StringIO(urllib.urlopen("http://i.imgur.com/IIv3E1K.jpg").read())))

    # swap around axes and drop two of the three layers (they're all identical)
    terrain_image = numpy.swapaxes(terrain_image, 2, 1)
    terrain_image = numpy.swapaxes(terrain_image, 0, 1)
    terrain_image = terrain_image[0]

    print "Terrain Image Parsed!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In Linux, I get this:

```
Terrain Image Parsed!
```

In osx:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 14, in main
    terrain_image = terrain_image[0]
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Why is there this discrepancy?

Comment: sure, that this code produces the error? work's for me on linux and mac. What are the dimensions of the arrays?

Comment: huh. I got the error report from my client who said that it didn't work for him.

Comment: What if the call to ``urllib.urlopen()`` fails?

Comment: The original code didn't have that. It used `Image.open(local_filename)`. I added in the url support for easy SO debugging.

Comment: I'll have to debug further to find out exactly what's the difference between  my system and my client's.

Comment: I ve seen now you are trying a deploy and it is there it is misbehaving - you definitely should be using a virtualenv, with a "setup.py" file which ensures the same versions of all Python modules, if you are not doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a bad guess - 
First thing to do is to put the call to "Image.open (...)" in a separate line, and either print, debug or otherwise introspect the resulting object
to see if you actually have an Image at this point. Do the same for your array object.

If you get a proper image (and whether the array looks strange or not), them my guess kicks in -  the current modern form of opening an image, is using `from PIL import Image` - as Pillow, the maintained fork of the Python-imaging -library deprecated the use of simple `import Image`.
The fact the error is no in the `import Image` line suggests you are using  an outdated Python-Imaging-Library.  I suggest uninstalling "PIL" (or Python-PIL) from your project - if you are (as you should) using a Python package isolation mechanism, such as virtualenv - and installing the drop-in replacement "pillow" instead. (And of course, changing said line to `from PIL import Image`)

If you are using system-libraries, check if your Linux distro has a package for Pillow (instead of PIL) and install that. Otherwise, you will have to resort to a virtualenv or similar mechanism where you can provide Pillow without interfering with the remaining of your system. (Deleting the package manager provided Pillow in any Linux distribution for a system-wide pillow - installed Python side, via PIP - could be catastrophic, as the system will remove every package that depends on PIL as it won't "see" it)

And them again, this may not be the error cause at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input. I have uninstalled `python-pil` and installed `python-pillow` only to discover that the one is just an alias of the other in my repo. In aptitude it indicates that the `python-pil` is the pillow fork. So everything is correct on my side as far as PIL is concerned (Debian Jessie). So that leaves the osx side. I'll check if my client has pillow installed or PIL.